# aws sdk v3 for subscribing to IOT topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I have used
`import { IoTDataPlaneClient,PublishCommand,} from '@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane';` by using v3 sdk
to publish a message to MQTT test client. Whats the library for subscribing to a topic ?

```
import { IoTDataPlaneClient,PublishCommand,} from '@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane';
async connect() {
    console.log('IOT gateway up');

    const payload = {
      username: 'Deepak',
      password: 'test',
    };

    const input = {
      topic: 'test/testt',
      payload: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)),
    };
    const command = new PublishCommand(input);
    try {
      const data = await this.client.send(command);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: if you want to handle/ print the message published to the topic: go to IoT core > rules, create a rule; configure a sql stmt `SELECT * FROM 'test/testt'` & attach a lambda handler function to print the event: `async hanler_fn(event, context) => {
  console.log(event);}`

Comment: @nbs I am sorry. Thats not what i needed. I need command like 'subscribeCommand'.
I got the 'publishCommand' from '@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane'.
So, i need to get where i can get the subscribeCommand ?

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure if there is a v3; see if this helps..  
Aws device sdk [Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html), where you may see [aws-iot-device-sdk v2](https://aws.github.io/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/node/index.html) , [pub/sub](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/blob/main/samples/node/pub_sub_mqtt5) samples etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no `subscribe` since the SDK is not using MQTT but HTTPS.
If you want to subscribe, you need to use the AWS IoT Device SDK nodejs.

Here is the link: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/device-example.js

Comment: I am also failed to found a proper code for subscripting messages in aws iot sdk version two. I have been able complete it in v1 but i would like to have that in V2.
Could you help me with that ?

Comment: Finally solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527295/aws-iot-sdk-gives-error-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly

Comment: As I said, the AWS SDK doesn't have MQTT, you need AWS IoT Device SDK, that's the link I posted.