# AWS IOT SDK gives error : The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, mqtt, aws-iot

I was trying to connect AWS IOT using latest version of AWS device sdk. But i am getting connection closed error. This is my Nest.js code that i am using to connect.
i am getting the error : "Failed to connect: libaws-c-mqtt: AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP, The connection was closed unexpectedly."

```
    import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { io, iot, mqtt } from 'aws-iot-device-sdk-v2';
    import * as path from 'path';
    @Injectable()
    export class AppService  {
      

      async build_connection(): Promise<mqtt.MqttClientConnection> {
        const aws_region = 'ap-south-1';
        const aws_access_id = 'AKIxxxW4GAPQU4IQH4';
        const aws_secret_key = 'HRbia73xxxHqgPgS7ybiP95nLnURxX3O0HZaZS';

        const ca_file = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/certs/AmazonRootCA1.pem');
        const cert = path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          '../src/certs/96cf4fd7b42e237cf3e6505822cb89a71d2bff29e0149bc68b2536198e5cba6e.certificate.pem.crt',
        );
        const key = path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          '../src/certs/96cf4fd7b42e237cf3e6505822cb89a72d1bff29e0149bc68b2536198e5cba6e.private.pem.key',
        );
        const dirpath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/certs/');
        console.log(cert);
        const client_id = 'Nestcms123';
        const endpoint = 'a3cz63qenxx11e-ats.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com';
        const config_builder =
          iot.AwsIotMqttConnectionConfigBuilder.new_mtls_builder_from_path(
            cert,
            key,
          );
        const client_bootstrap = new io.ClientBootstrap();

        config_builder.with_certificate_authority_from_path(undefined, ca_file);
        config_builder.with_clean_session(false);
        config_builder.with_client_id(client_id);
        //config_builder.with_keep_alive_seconds(5);
        config_builder.with_endpoint(endpoint);
        //config_builder.with_port(8883);
        config_builder.with_credentials(aws_region, aws_access_id, aws_secret_key);
        const config = config_builder.build();
        const client = new mqtt.MqttClient(client_bootstrap);
        const connection = client.new_connection(config);
        connection.on('error', function () {
          console.log('errrror');
        });
        return connection;
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use acces key and cert at the same time? It doesn’t make sense. Use certificate and private key. Also, make sure the iot policy attached to your cert in aws iot has the right permissions.

Comment: Thank you
 solved by adjusting permissions in the policy